# Is there a way to render HTML with react native expo for web?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-webview

I know the web view works well for **Android** and **IOS** https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/webview/. Although it is not available for web build of the expo as of now.

My use case is that I want to integrate a complete HTML based template in my expo web build for a specific screen with internal CSS and scripts.

I am open to other solutions and workarounds.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Render conditionally like Platform.os === 'android', show webview else render direct HTML. Simple..

Answer (score 0):

In reality react native web uses react to render things. So

```js
if(Platform.OS === "web"){
  <div></div> //etc or call a function that returns html
}else{
 ---- //Normal rendering
}
```

Comment: It's only for HTML elements like div and others. what about script tags, and style tags. Would they work normally as they do in a normal HTML page with this approach?

Comment: I wonder Why you can not use React directly instead?. Can you check if it is possible to `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`